# Noun for person who tells how not to do something, and then does it

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, nouns

Okay so I'm sure many people have seen this happen before and it tends to happen apparently intentionally, in more of a way to seem comical, but here is the example for what I am talking about:

> "You don't want to over-season the fish at all now..." -*covers the
>   entire bowl with seasoning*- "Alright now we'll season the other side.
>   Just remember to not season it too much now..." -*pretty much uses an
>   entire bottle of seasoning*-

So the first word I thought for this would be a "hypocrite", but I don't think it would accurately describe the situation here. To me, a hypocrite is more of this:

> "Stop smacking while eating dude that's annoying." -*smacks loudly
>   while eating*-

Sorry if this doesn't make any sense, but I was just wondering if there was another word (preferably a noun) that more accurately describes the first example.

Comment: Is the idea that the person is doing this intentionally (for example, to seem comical), or unintentionally?

Comment: @sumelic Yes I would assume so because it is so extremely obvious.

Comment: I edited your question to try to clarify it; please change it if I introduced anything you don't like. I think "hypocrite" is still the best word.

Comment: @sumelic I don't know about you, but to me a hypocrite tends to have a negative connotation, right? Also many times a hypocrite will say not to do something to somebody, but then do that thing behind their back (and not obviously). With the definition I described, like I said, they are doing it very obviously and sort of comically.

Comment: We have a similar personality in our friends circle. We call him an Oxy**moron**! :P

Comment: In scholastics, the single word for this is 'teaching', and the person who does it is a 'teacher'. These words convey the "sort of comical" connotation also. Beyond English, *mali exempli* ('of bad example') is the phrase in Latin; *de mauvis exemple* in French.

Comment: If your audience is familiar with Aesop's Fables, you might refer to such a person as being ["the crab's mother](http://mythfolklore.net/aesopica/milowinter/3.htm)."

Comment: @BiscuitBoy That is a good one in my opinion, not sure it is the best though! Thanks to everybody who has gave ideas.

Comment: @JEL That makes a lot of sense; showing somebody how to do something the right way by doing it the wrong way. However, one would not know that the "teacher" in this case is actually doing it wrong because they never explicitly pointed out that fact. Even though it is noticeable by people who have a more common sense, the idea might fly over one's head.

Comment: @SvenYargs I like that, but the thing is that it does not represent the idea in a single word or short idea. But, like you said, if I had an audience to explain this to I would *definitely* use your example!

Comment: Oh, it's used for comic effect. Hell man, that makes mincemeat of my suggestion :) A sort of "[**do as I say, not as I do**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Do+as+I+say,+not+as+I+do)" angle.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yeah I feel like there really is no word for this exact thing in the context of comedy, so any word that relates to the situation without attention to the comical intention should work!

Comment: I think 'clown' probably conveys what you want fairly well.

Comment: I think the guy Is just ***absentminded***.  He’s so focused on teaching that he’s not paying attention to what he’s doing.  Or maybe ***distracted***

Comment: @Jim Good point, but like I said it is intentional in some forms of comedy. Of course, the effect in the comedy may be of an absent minded character, but who knows!

Answer (score 3):

> **[contradictory](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contradictory)** (Wiktionary)
>   3. That is diametrically opposed to something.

A common idiom that describes the scenario described by the OP would be:
**[practise what you preach](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/practise-what-you-preach)**

e.g. *That TV cook's advice is contradictory, he doesn't practise what he preaches*

Comment: What about a noun form of this? Just "contradictory person"? I like this word for it because it remains relatively neutral. But what do you think about the word "antithetic"?

Comment: A "contradictory person" could work, but maybe contrarian is better. Your suggestion,  antithetic, is good, but I confess I had to double-check its meaning.

Comment: A *contrarian* is someone who takes the less popular route. I doubt if it could fit OP's context of obnoxious hypocrisy.

Comment: @sumelic Thanks for pointing that out. I was comparing the word to "hypocrite", so I thought it was obvious, Sorry!

Comment: In an appropriate context, [contrarian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contrarian) might work, e.g. *He's always doing the opposite of what he says, he's a bit of a contrarian.* But... the dictionary definition doesn't really support this usage.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yeah, I'd agree that your usage *contradicts* the dictionary's. Most of the examples for "contrarian" are relating to one doing the opposite of society, while this is about one doing the opposite of their own instructions/advice.

Answer (score 1):

The guy's a ***phony***.

Another good word would be ***mountebank***, but it's almost never used these days.

[Mountebank](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mountebank?s=t):

> a person who sells quack medicines, as from a platform in public
>   places, attracting and influencing an audience by tricks,
>   storytelling, etc.
>
> any charlatan or quack.

[Dictionary.com]

Comment: Ooh!  A driveby downvote.  Should be fodder for your next meta post.

Comment: It's an okay solution, better than just a hypocrite. But then again a phony has a negative connotation too, right?

@deadrat I hope you know it wasn't me! I can't rate people with my current reputation anyways.

Comment: Hi, Ricky, I fixed a typo and copied and pasted essential part of the source.

Comment: @Shortninja No, I didn't think it was you.  People who ask good questions tend to explain why answers don't meet their needs.

Comment: +1 for *phony*, but the second one is off target in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

***[Inconsistent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inconsistent)*** may apply:

> - Displaying or marked by a lack of consistency, especially:
>
>   - not regular or predictable; erratic: *inconsistent behavior.*
>   - lacking in correct logical relation; contradictory: *inconsistent statements*.

The Free Dictionary

Comment: That makes sense to me. I wonder if there is a noun for this besides "inconsistent person", though! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be called ***double standards***: someone tells you not to do something, then does that thing or allows others to do it.

> My boss told me not to eat at the desk, then walked straight past my co-worker who was eating at his desk, without any complaints may I add. She really has double standards.